# Seleção automática em menu drop-down

Tags: php

Em um programa para previsão meteorológica por selecção de cidades estou usando uma dropbox que funciona bem, mas o sistema não está totalmente automático. Quando é iniciado, preciso de selecionar uma cidade para mostrar a previsão. O que eu pretendia é que a lista não tivesse "Selecionar cidade" e abrisse logo com a previsão para a primeira cidade (Caldas da Rainha). Muito obrigado por qualquer dica (sou principiante!) :-)

 O site é esse [1]: http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao3.php

 O código é esse: `

```html
<?php

$arr = ["Caldas da Rainha", "Lisboa", "Peniche" ];
if( $_POST['city']){
   $city=$_POST['city'];
}
?>

<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
<select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
  <option value="0">Selecione cidade</option>
  <?php

   foreach ($arr as $a){

    if($a == $city){
        echo "<option value='{$a}' selected >$a</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option value='{$a}' >$a</option>";
    }

   }

   ?>
  
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Mas aí vc deveria já abrir a página com os dados do "Caldas da Rainha". Seu formulário faz um POST. Não faz sentido fazer um POST automático ao abrir a página. Vc pode mostrar já na abertura da página os dados que vc quiser.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sam. Compreendo o que você disse de que não faz sentido fazer um post automático ao abrir a página, mas em meu site [link] http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao.php [/link] há esse caso parecido e funciona. Vou tentar analisar melhor e descobrir porque razão não está mostrando dados quando abre a página [link] http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao3.php [/link]

Comment: Analisando melhor, parece ser porque $city que é necessária para mostrar os dados, só fica disponível depois do primeiro click em uma das cidades. Terá jeito de $city ficar disponível logo que a página abre na primeira cidade e sem ser preciso clicar? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Para ficar totalmente automático e mostrar a previsão quando abre a página precisou apenas de adicionar $city = $arr[0] antes de if( $_POST['city']. Muito obrigado uma vez mais.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente tirar o  e a a sua lógica que estará resolvido.
Retire este trecho:

```
<option value="0">Selecione cidade</option>
```

Ficará assim:

```html
<?php
$arr = ["Caldas da Rainha", "Lisboa", "Peniche" ];
?>

<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
<select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
  <?php
   foreach ($arr as $a){
        echo "<option value='{$a}'>$a</option>";
   }

   ?>
  
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Felipe! Retirei o <option value="0">Selecione cidade</option> e a coisa melhorou porque agora o menu mostra logo a primeira cidade. Ainda subsiste um problema: a previsão para essa cidade não inicia automaticamente. Para ver a previsão da primeira cidade tenho que clicar noutra cidade e depois voltar à primeira cidade para ela mostrar a previsão. Será que existe algum jeito de contornar este problema? Mais uma vez agradecimento especial Filipe, por sua resposta ter sido tão rápida e tão útil.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Para ficar totalmente automático precisou apenas de adicionar $city = $arr[0] antes de if( $_POST['city']. Muito obrigado uma vez mais.